# Java library for extended attributes, typing and validation

Tags: attributes, properties, object-model, java

Background: I have an object model that needs to be extended by adding several attributes to a few types, which can vary across installations. For example, my 'user' objects need to have a few extended attributes. On some sites 'users' need several identifiers whereas in other sites 'users' need other attributes like extra phone numbers, addresses and dates. I prefer to avoid maintaining several object models and interfaces, and instead model this as "extensible object properties".

Question: Is there a Java library that can handle type definitions, providing typed property bags, methods to list properties, enforce typing, validate values, convert values to and from String, and maybe help with the related SQL queries and form processing...?

I need to be able to define types and attributes programatically. Ability to load type definitions from configuration files would be desirable.

Comments are very welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right it is barely possible in scala with trait mechanizm, which is like Interfaces you may mixin in some class, but may contain code, so you don't need to rewrite abstract methods all the times you use them.

```
trait Stackoverflow {
   val foo = "FOO"
}

trait MetaStackoverflow {
   val bar = "BAR"
}

class User(val name: String)
```

now in REPL:

```
scala> val u = new User("jjmontes") with Stackoverflow with MetaStackoverflow   
//u: User with Stackoverflow with MetaStackoverflow = $anon$1@8825a5

scala> u.bar  
//res0: java.lang.String = BAR

scala> u.foo  
//res1: java.lang.String = FOO
```

Or like this:

```
scala> class UserA(name: String) extends User(name) with Stackoverflow
//defined class UserA

scala> val u = new UserA("jjmontes")
//u: UserA = UserA@1aecf45

scala> u.foo
//res8: java.lang.String = FOO

scala> u.bar
<console>:12: error: value bar is not a member of UserA
              u.bar
```

Scala has almost full interop with Java (except a some rare cases, where it is still has interop, but painful).

Comment: Wow! Thanks, this answer is the closest to what I was looking for :). I don't need this now, bot from my research, and I think there is a niche for these kind of libraries (typed domain objects over a given language).

Comment: As a side note, many enterprise systems have this (SAP, OpenERP, Documentum...), so I find this is a very typical design issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult in java. But, of course, you have Properties :-)

You can use Groovy, or Javascript.

In java, you can use perhaps some *string-object-document*, with Properties, or with XML, Json, Yaml.

Comment: I was looking for a library that allows me to define a few types (userA, userB, documentA, documentB), and 1) use its API to list the properties of a given type, or 2) to create instances of the property bags, while the properties preserve typing, and 3) to be able to load those properties from a ResultSet.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think it's impossible and irrelevant in java. In java you define type with source code, it's all, and it's good. You don"t define type with library. Perhaps see JPA to partially do want you want.

Comment: With JPA object model also needs to be defined at design time. I wish to manage domain object definitions (types, attributes) as configuration, in the same way as some database systems or ECM like Documentum do. This way, adding an attribute to an object becomes a configuration issue instead of requiring developer intervention. In order to achieve that, I was looking for a library that would manage type and attribute definitions for me. I guess my question was too broad.